# How to turn off all WordPress commenting

Tags: wordpress

In my WordPress site, I did the following:

1. Went to Settings / Discussion and unchecked "Allow people to post comments on new articles".
2. Went to Posts / All Posts, selected all, select EDIT under Bulk Actions, selected Do Not Allow, then clicked Update.

Yet, I am still getting emails "A new comment on the post *_* is waiting for your approval". And its always spam.

How do I make this stop?

Thank you!

Comment: How about a plugin? http://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-comments/

Answer (score 2):

Add this code to your theme's function.php file

```
// Close comments on the front-end
    function df_disable_comments_status() {
        return false;
    }
    add_filter('comments_open', 'df_disable_comments_status', 20, 2);
    add_filter('pings_open', 'df_disable_comments_status', 20, 2);

    // Hide existing comments
    function df_disable_comments_hide_existing_comments($comments) {
        $comments = array();
        return $comments;
    }
    add_filter('comments_array', 'df_disable_comments_hide_existing_comments', 10, 2);
```

It will turn off your all comments
Thanks

Comment: Comments disabled, but it still shows on the page before comments section the total number of comments for this page: 1 Comment

Answer (score 0):

Edit a post or page and :

- Under the text area, if there is a discussion box, make sure `Allow comments.` box is unticked.
- In the top right hand side of the page there is the `Screen Options` tab, click that and make sure the discussion box is unticked.

That should do it.

Comment: On further examination, it appears that these spam comments are being added to MEDIA items. Specifically, old graphics that were either part of WordPress or the theme, and aren't even used in the website. When I go under Screen Options, discussion is already unticked. And I don't see anywhere else for comments to be allowed, so I'm confused as to why anyone is able to add comments. I guess the easy solution to just delete these unnecessary graphics, but still wondering why it was possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm placing this as an answer because I do not have enough reputation points to comment but What Howlin meant to say is.  If you do not see the discussion box under the text area that has an option to Allow Comments, Go to Screen Options and make sure the discussion box it is Checked.

The Screen Options allow you to check or uncheck different Options panels that will display on the screen.  So by checking the Discussion Box you will display a panel under the text area that has an option to Allow or Disallow Comments.  That gives you another option to regulate discussion on a per page or post basis.